# Multi step Copy and paste VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pull data (cells) from four test result (each a different excel file) so that the average can be calculated within the template. Then to loop and do the same thing with the next four test but have the VBA script place y cells down. I'm trying to do exactly the following,

1. To protect the cells except for certain ones for data input.- Done
2. Upon pushing an inserted button run a VBA script that will copy and paste certain cells from four other excel workbooks. Done
3. After those four are copy and pasted, for the VBA script to loop but paste y amount cells down.
4. And last to force save as for this is a public template and don't want it to be changed.

I'm having trouble with 3-4, So far i have the following for code..., but i haven't done very much of this to know order/ correct code commands.

What i Have so Far

**Step 1:Done**

```
Sub ProtectSheetDataInput ()

Worksheets("DataInput").Cells.Locked = False
Worksheets("DataInput").Range("A1:B283,C1:N3").Locked = True
Worksheets("DataInput").Protect Password:="----coop", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

**Step 2: Done**

```
'Separate Macro    

Sub DataTransfer()

Dim w As Workbook 'Test_Location 1
Dim x As Workbook 'Test_Location 2
Dim y As Workbook 'Test_Location 3
Dim z As Workbook 'Test_Location 4
Dim Alpha As Workbook 'Template

Set w = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_1.xls")
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_2.xls")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_3.xls")
Set z = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_4.xls")
Set Alpha = Workbooks("FRF_Data_Sheet_Template.xlsm")

    Alpha.Sheets("DataInput").Range("C4:E8").Value = w.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Value
    Alpha.Sheets("DataInput").Range("F4:H8").Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Value
    Alpha.Sheets("DataInput").Range("I4:K8").Value = y.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Value
    Alpha.Sheets("DataInput").Range("L4:N8").Value = z.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Value

    w.Close False
    x.Close False
    y.Close False
    z.Close False

End Sub
```

**Step 3 Update:** Tired to do a If find blank in Column C then Paste... did not work. Error at

```
 If Columns("C").Value = "" Then
```

"type mismatch"

```
Sub DataTransfer()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim w As Workbook 'Test_Location 1
Dim x As Workbook 'Test_Location 2
Dim y As Workbook 'Test_Location 3
Dim z As Workbook 'Test_Location 4
Dim Alpha As Workbook 'Template
Dim Emptyrow As Long 'Next Empty Row

    Set w = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_1.xls")
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_2.xls")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_3.xls")
    Set z = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_4.xls")
    Set Alpha = Workbooks("FRF_Data_Sheet_Template.xlsm")

        If Columns("C").Value = "" Then
            Alpha.Sheets("DataInput").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = w.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Value
            Alpha.Sheets("DataInput").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = x.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Value
            Alpha.Sheets("DataInput").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = y.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Value
            Alpha.Sheets("DataInput").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = z.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Value

            w.Close False
            x.Close False
            y.Close False
            z.Close False
        End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Then i Tried a different approach, I got this to work between 2 worksheets but i cant get it to work Between Multiple Workbooks. I get 'Runtime Error '9' Subscript out of range for this line.

```
Alpha.Sheets(DataInput).Activate
```

'

```
Sub DataTransfer()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim w As Workbook 'Test_Location 1
Dim x As Workbook 'Test_Location 2
Dim y As Workbook 'Test_Location 3
Dim z As Workbook 'Test_Location 4
Dim Alpha As Workbook 'Template
Dim Emptyrow As Range

    Set w = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_1.xls")
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_2.xls")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_3.xls")
    Set z = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\location_4.xls")
    Set Alpha = Workbooks("FRF_Data_Sheet_Template.xlsm")
    Set EmptyrowC = Range("C" & Sheets("DataInput").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    Set EmptyrowF = Range("F" & Sheets("DataInput").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    Set EmptyrowI = Range("I" & Sheets("DataInput").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    Set EmptyrowL = Range("L" & Sheets("DataInput").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)

        w.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Copy
        Alpha.Sheets(DataInput).Active
            NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Set NextRow = Nothing
        x.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Copy
            Alpha.Sheets(DataInput).Active
            NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Set NextRow = Nothing
        y.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Copy
            Alpha.Sheets(DataInput).Active
            NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Set NextRow = Nothing
        z.Sheets("Data").Range("I3:K7").Copy
            Alpha.Sheets(DataInput).Active
            NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Set NextRow = Nothing

        w.Close False
        x.Close False
        y.Close False
        z.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You could do a copy to destination instead.
`y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F5").Copy  destination:=x.Sheets("InputSheet").Range("A1:F5")`

Comment: `'it doesnt like the last line`? What error do you get?

Comment: Run time error '91' object variable or block variable not set.

Comment: no matter what, you have to tell it what X is. just telling the compiler X is a workbook only gets you 1/2 way there.  Set X to be the name of the ActiveWorkbook (or whatever the name of the source workbook is) should get you closer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This one wont work, it opens the out put but doesn't copy the cells

I don't see you opening the `X` Workbook.

This works for me just fine, provided the cell in `y.Sheets("Sheet1")` are unlocked.

Also notice the use of `.Value` on both ends.

```
Sub DataTransfer()
    Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook

    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Test_output.xlsm")
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Blah Blah\Blah.xlsm") '<~~ Change as Applicable

    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F5").Value = x.Sheets("InputSheet").Range("A1:F5").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me try some of the things suggested and ill get back asap. I did not open X workbook because its going to be open already. The macro run button is in the X workbook.

Comment: If it is already open then also you need to initialize `x` For example `Set X = Workbooks("Blah.xlsm")`

Comment: Error '9' Subscript out of range     Set x = Workbooks("C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Test_input.xlsm")

Comment: `Set x = Workbooks("Test_input.xlsm")`

Comment: Boom! Step 1 and 2 complete! Thank you so much! Any advice on the rest of what im trying to do? step 3 and 4?

Comment: Sure but first post the code that you tried and show us where are you stuck

Comment: I put it in the OP under Update, Before i was just testing between 2 files now i have the actual files ill be using. I dont know how to loop the copy paste so it paste down to the next empty cells.

Comment: Yes but that code doesn't show what have you tried for points 3rd and 4th.  Please show what have you tried and specially where are you stuck?

Comment: I havent tried anything yet for 3 and 4 because i dont know what i should try, Im new to this... It needs to repeat each time i press a macro linked button but with the row change. Im stuck on what to do next

Comment: I know you  haven't tried anything and hence I want you to try something. :) Do some research in google and stackoverflow. Try and record a macro and see how the code works out. And then when you have tried it, post a new question with the code that you tried and then we will take it from there. I am sorry but I do not give code in a platter.

Answer (score 0):

Copy to destination instead.

```
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F5").Copy _           
   destination:=x.Sheets("InputSheet").Range("A1:F5")
```

Comment: `Copy to destination instead.`? Why? what is wrong with OP's original approach?

Comment: Without knowing the source and destination, the values won't work with merged cells, which will cause an error.  Your other option is to figure out what's actually causing the problem and address that.